# recursion resulting in extra unwanted data

Tags: java, recursion, dice

I'm writing a module to handle dice rolling.  Given x die of y sides, I'm trying to come up with a list of all potential roll combinations.

This code assumes 3 die, each with 3 sides labeled 1, 2, and 3.  (I realize I'm using "magic numbers" but this is just an attempt to simplify and get the base code working.)

```
        int[] set = { 1, 1, 1 };
        list = diceroll.recurse(0,0, list, set);

...

    public ArrayList<Integer> recurse(int index, int i, ArrayList<Integer> list, int[] set){
        if(index < 3){
//          System.out.print("\n(looping on "+index+")\n");
            for(int k=1;k<=3;k++){
//              System.out.print("setting i"+index+" to "+k+" ");
                set[index] = k;
                dump(set);
                recurse(index+1, i, list, set);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

(dump() is a simple method to just display the contents of list[]. The variable **i** is not used at the moment.)

What I'm attempting to do is increment a list[index] by one, stepping through the entire length of the list and incrementing as I go.

This is my "best attempt" code.  Here is the output:

Bold output is what I'm looking for.  I can't figure out how to get rid of the rest.  (This is assuming three dice, each with 3 sides.  Using recursion so I can scale it up to any x dice with y sides.)

> [1][1][1] [1][1][1]
>
> **[1][1][1] [1][1][2] [1][1][3]** [1][2][3]
>
> **[1][2][1] [1][2][2] [1][2][3]** [1][3][3]
>
> **[1][3][1] [1][3][2] [1][3][3]** [2][3][3] [2][1][3]
>
> **[2][1][1] [2][1][2] [2][1][3]** [2][2][3]
>
> **[2][2][1] [2][2][2] [2][2][3]** [2][3][3]
>
> **[2][3][1] [2][3][2] [2][3][3]** [3][3][3] [3][1][3]
>
> **[3][1][1] [3][1][2] [3][1][3]** [3][2][3]
>
> **[3][2][1] [3][2][2] [3][2][3]** [3][3][3]
>
> **[3][3][1] [3][3][2] [3][3][3]**

I apologize for the formatting, best I could come up with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  (This method was actually stemmed to use the data for something quite trivial, but has turned into a personal challenge. :)

edit: If there is another approach to solving this problem I'd be all ears, but I'd also like to solve my current problem and successfully use recursion for something useful.

edit2:
Running code including the "easy fix."  Beware unused variables and weird hacks, I haven't cleaned it up yet.

```
package code.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CodeTesting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int[] set = { 1, 1, 1 };
        list = recurse(0,0, list, set);
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> recurse(int index, int i, ArrayList<Integer> list, int[] set){
        if(index < 3){
//          System.out.print("\n(looping on "+index+")\n");
            for(int k=1;k<=3;k++){
//              System.out.print("setting i"+index+" to "+k+" ");
                set[index] = k;
                if (index==2){
                    dump(set);
                }
                recurse(index+1, i, list, set);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    static void dump(int[] arr) {
        for (int s : arr) {
            System.out.format("[%s]", s);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry I had to rewrite the code, but it's pretty much the same algorithm as yours with some corrections:

```
public class DiceRolls {
    static void recurse(int diceNumber, int[] values, final int MAX) {
        if (diceNumber == values.length) {
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(values));
        } else {
            for (int v = 1; v <= MAX; v++) {
                values[diceNumber] = v;
                recurse(diceNumber + 1, values, MAX);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recurse(0, new int[3], 4);
    }
}
```

This is a standard tuplet recursive generator. If you want to add all the `int[]` into a `List`, then make sure to `add(values.clone())` so they are independent `int[]` objects.

---

#### But what's with the extra output?

The problem is that you were dumping prematurely, before you're done throwing all the dices. In pseudocode, this is what you're doing:

```
if we're not done yet
    trying all possibilities for this dice
       dump result so far // premature dumping!
       recurse for next dice
```

An easy fix to your code is to do the following:

```
if we're not done yet
    trying all possibilities for this dice
       recurse for next dice
else, we're done, so
    dump result // timely!
```

So back to the Java implementation, the fix is merely moving `dump(set);` to an `else` case for the `if (index < 3)` statement.

Comment: Updated to post my awful (runnable) as per request.  At this point I think its just for the LOL factor.

I appreciate the proper, clean method, as well as the reasoning to why my code was broken.  As this was my first attempt at "real" (useful) recursion, I'll certainly be ripping apart what you've posted to get a better feel for things.  Thank you!

Comment: @spacerace: I recommend http://codingbat.com/java as a good source of practice problems. It has a recursion section, though it's somewhat limited for now. Oh, and I deleted my comment asking for more complete code, as you can see. I think what you had was fine, I was just not paying enough attention.

Answer (score 1):

Call `dump()` only when `index == 2`.

Incidentally, `i` and `list` seem unused. And the verb is "recur". :)

Comment: That works perfectly.  It took me a second to figure out why it worked.  It seems like a kind of a sneaky hack.  I'm going to play with this as well as polygenelubricants's code for some good ol' learnin.  Thank you!

Comment: Well, `index == 2` is really your base case, and the point is output happens in the base case of the recursion. It ought to be `index == set.length-1` or something if that's what you mean, but otherwise it's appropriate. Yes you can rewrite the code as in other answers to make it come out more nicely, in a way that shows this is actually what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-recursive alternative. Change the two constants to calculate all combinations for different dices and different numbers of dice.

```
package utils;

public class Dice {
    private static int FACES = 3;
    private static int NUMBER_OF_DICE = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start = createPair(1);
        int end = createPair(FACES);
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            String combination = Integer.toString(i, FACES+1);
            if (combination.indexOf('0') < 0)
                System.out.println(combination);
        }
    }

    private static int createPair(int number) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_DICE; i++) {
            sb.append(number);
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(sb.toString(), FACES+1);
    }
}
```